# Edit layered navigation filter titles in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have layered navigation on my website as follows:

Category

Price

Size

I would like to edit the title of the filters. For example, change 'Category' to 'Product Type'... how can this be done in Magento?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For Price and Size all you have to do is to change the title of attribute in Catalog -> Attributes -> Attribute Sets -> ATTRIBUTE -> Attribute Information -> Manage Label/Option